# Advice on technology stack: Google App Engine, FLEX, GraniteDS (Tide), Java, Spring 

Tags: java, apache-flex, spring, google-app-engine, graniteds

Friends,

Your technology stack is the rope that will save you or hang you. For a one man webservice startup - what kind of rope is this list?

Plattform: Google App Engine, Backend: Google App Engine Datastore, Servicelayer: Java, 
Frontend: Adobe Flex

Client/Service integration framework: GraniteDS, Client Application Framework: Tide (Part of the GraniteDS stack), Service Application Framework: Spring

---

Ok, let me give you my context.

Flextras is right! Technology is mostly chosen because of knowledge/infrastructure ... This is how I ended up with the list given above:

First of all: FLEX appeals to me. It’s easy to build rich UIs and Adobe is pushing it in the direction Desktop, web and devices. Adobe marketing gives us the promise: ”Integrate with the other tools in the creative suite” and ”Deploy everywhere”. (Of course it’s too good to be true, but they seem to be on the right track.) So lets choose FLEX as our UI framework.

FLEX often must integrate with serverside technology. So what technology to choose for the service layer? I know PHP of old, but the dynamic, untyped feel of the language, just doesn’t feel right working side by side with flex.

Flex draws much of it’s inspiration from Java. And thinking in ActionScript and thinking in Java just feels right. (I’ve explored Scala but the tooling and best practices are not there yet for someone like me to adopt this great new language). I’ve chosen to learn java, hoping that it will make patterns and knowledge reusable between the server-side-programming and the client-side-programming.

The problem with java is it’s complexity and that it’s harder to deploy (for PHP you could easily deploy on a cheep webhotel). My idea is a test and I don’t want costs and servers (who does?). I want to focus on exploring my ideas. So I’m looking at Google App Engine who offers a free amount of Java quota for a startup web applications.

The problem with Google App engine is that it’s restrictive Sandbox model, and many frameworks doesn’t deploy as is.

I want a technology line that will work together with a minimum amount of hacking. And this is where I’m asking for your expertise, helping me choose the right frameworks for integrating FLEX with Java on the Google App engine.

I want to use strongly typed objects from server to client so I’m looking for an AMF solution. From what I can tell looking at forums BlazeDS needs hacking, Pimento/Cinnamon doesn’t work, Weborb or Adobe Livecykle aren’t free. GraniteDS however seams to be working on the Google app store without patching.

GraniteDS comes with a client framework called Tide that integrates with serverside technologies. But once again Google App Engine is a restrictive environment. Seam (which seams to integrate the best with Tide) seams to be a hack job on Google app engine. EJB3 or CDI is Java EE 6 technologies and not supported by Jetty (the servlet container powering Google App Engine). Spring seams like a viable candidate however.

The Google app engine dosen’t have a relational database, but has interfaced It’s new datastore behind the JPA interface that both Spring and Tide (GraniteDS) supports.

I’m not sure all this rambling makes any of us any the wiser.

What I’m asking is this: From FLEX to the Google App Store, what line of technologies gives me the least rope to hang myself with? Im suggesting Tide/GraniteDS/Java/Spring/JPA. But what do I know until I’ve tried it.

Comment: I voted to close; as without a description of the purpose; it is impossible to evaluate any technology as good or bad.  It's like saying "I need to build something; what type of nails should I use."  You're gonna want to use different nails for a bird house vs a skyscraper.

Comment: Please bare with me. Rockstar programmers can use the ”right” tool in the ”right” situations. They know how to build the custom solutions to make one ”right” tool work together with another ”best” tool -  how to get from the ”best” database to the ”best” client framework. But the rest of us ... we need to compromise for a stack that works together out of the boxes. My question is not about what pieces I need to build something that I’m not telling you about. The question is: will I be able to punch this kind of nails in to this kind of wall using this tool?

Comment: For example: If someone asked me if FLEX, BlazeDS, Java and Google App Engine is a good technology stack I would have answered him that BlazeDS docent work on google app engine without patching it. That kind of knowledge is worth a lot to someone trying to determine what frameworks to invest in. (Love the flex show by the way. Please keep up the good work!)

Comment: Will you be able to punch *WHAT* kind of nail to *WHAT* kind of wall using *WHAT* tool?  The answer is a resounding 'yes'; give enough time and budget.  But, I still feel it's impossible to answer the question w/o some parameters.  Reality is that you can choose any database or application server; or UI tool to get things done. There is enough encapsulation on either 'side' of those that the stack doesn't matter.  You can mix & match.  In my experience, I found that technology is rarely chosen based on technical merit, but rather for business reasons (such as in house knowledge/infrastructure)

Comment: I'm going to side with Flextras here. This question is unanswerable without knowing what you're trying to accomplish.  You could use php if you want, I'm not sure what you mean by not being typed since AMF does type things.  If it's something simple enough, I'd say go with php, if you need something more robust, go with something else.

Answer (score -1):

Given the vagueness of the question:

I'm using Flex/Cairgorme/Blazeds/JBossAS/Oracle Java EE together for a mission critical, high performance, scalable application.  I would highly recommend this combo.